# v2 Azure Function with Service Bus trigger not firing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-keyvault

I am using Azure Functions V2 with a Service Bus trigger using 1.0.23 of the C# Functions SDK. I'm using the following approach to get secrets from KeyVault and use them within the settings of the triggers: [How to map Azure Functions secrets from Key Vault automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655284/how-to-map-azure-functions-secrets-from-key-vault-automatically/52656495#52656495)

The function, especially when it has done nothing for a while, doesn't fire when there are messages on the subscription. If I then go to the portal and execute manually (yes, that particular execution is fired with a null message) it kicks it into life and picks up the other messages on the queue and processes them correctly.

This obviously isn't ideally for our automated tests. Has anybody seen this, or know of anything that will help?

Also, the Function App is running on a consumption plan.

Comment: On what plan are you running your functions?

Comment: Good question @SebastianAchatz. I'm on a Consumption plan - added to the original question.

Comment: So having contacted Microsoft, they have confirmed that this approach does not work when on the consumption plan. See: comment by Paul Batum on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655284/how-to-map-azure-functions-secrets-from-key-vault-automatically/52656495#52656495

Answer (score 3):

**App Service Plan**

If you're using App Service plan then it's simple, just make use of **[Always on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#always-on)**

**Consumption Plan**

If you're using Consumption plan, the issue could be that your triggers did not sync properly with the Azure Infrastructure (Central Listener). It could have happened due to the way you deployed/edited your trigger related settings as explained in issue #210 below.

When you access the function directly from Portal, it might be forcing your function app to come alive, but as you can see that's only a workaround. Something similar is mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/229#issuecomment-290467793)

Take a look at these issues:

1. [Service Bus Topic Trigger goes to sleep - Consumption Plan](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2697)

   They also mention that it wakes up only on accessing it via the portal or calling a HTTP triggered function in the same app, which is similar to the behavior you are seeing.
2. [Issue #210](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/210) 
   [image]
3. [Issue #681](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/681#issuecomment-363208746)

There are 3 suggested ways to resolve it, mentioned as part of Issue #210 above

> In order to synchronize triggers when these deployment options are
>   used, open the Azure Portal and click the Refresh button, or make a
>   API call to the sync triggers endpoint:
>   https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/FunctionsWebDeploy.json#L90
>
> Powershell sample:
>   https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L360-L365

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are using the standard VSTS app service deploy step without the Web Deploy option selected. Syncing the triggers hasn't solved the issue :(

Comment: @pkunal7 ok got it. One of the suggestions in first issue link from answer is to check if the VSTS deployment task uses web deploy.. see here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2697#issuecomment-382807204 .. although I don't know enough about VSTS app service deploy to say it would make things work for sure.. do give it a try if it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar issue. ServiceBus connection was injected using ServiceBus value in ConnectionStrings section of Function configuration. This is enough when Function is in hot state but after transitioning to cold state AzureWebJobsServiceBus value is used to connect to service bus. So in my case setting AzureWebJobsServiceBus to ServiceBus connection string in Function configuration fixed this.