# Azure function trigger listener stops running abruptly

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I have a service bus trigger based Azure function deployed to an app service. The status of the function is shown as running in the portal. I have selected it to be based on Consumption plan. The problem is as follows:
After I deploy the function, it processes all the messages in the service bus and once the service bus has no new messages to be processed, I see a message in the application insights that:
`Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener' for function ..`

Once the listener is stopped, the function doesn't process any messages in the service bus until I open the portal and navigate to the function. On opening the function, I notice the function running again and processing the messages.

What could be the issue here? I would like the function to trigger as soon as a new message is added to the service bus.

PS: I have another function based on eventhub trigger and I see similar message there too.

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310577/13832613) can give you some inspiration

Answer (score 0):

Is the Service Bus connection string for the Function in question assigned only Listen rights? If yes, could you please check with a connection string that has Manage rights.

You can check the rights by navigating to the service bus namespace --> Shared access policy

[image]

[ Logically, it is monitored internally if there is any new message arrived. In case there is a new message, function should be invoked automatically.]

Comment: I've seen this question multiple times. Messages are processed until they are not with a clear message "Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener' for function ...". I question if that's an access policy issue, @jayachatterjee-msft.

Comment: @SeanFeldman Do you see this message often in Application Insight as an exception or a warning( just information)

Comment: I don't but I don't run Function in production ATM.